# Vector_Exercise - Program exits

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to solve a problem which is like, if you enter a name: Eve which have three letters, so the program will eliminate the suitor of the multiple of that letter. If the multiple exceeds the size of the vector, then it will return back from the first index and so on. Did a cin for string because I just need the first name.
The program exits after the input. Tried to comment the last for loop and it worked fine, but that's the main part. Appreciate help, thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 int nos,n; string name;
 cout<<"Enter Number of Suitors: "<<endl;
 cin>>nos;

 cout<<"Enter Your First Name: "<<endl;
 cin>>name;

 n=name.size();

 vector<int>suit(nos);

 for(int i=0;i<nos;i++)
 suit[i] = i+1;

 for(int i=0;i<nos;i++)
 cout<<suit[i]<<" "; 

 for(n=n-1;(suit.size()!=1);n+=n)
 {
  n = n%nos;       
  suit.erase(suit.begin(),suit.begin()+n);
 } 
 cout<<suit.front();

 system("pause");
 return 0;     
}//close main
```